# How do I change the last letter of a sting based on a user prompt

Tags: javascript

When I test the code it only runs the first if statement even when I change the other if statements to else if

```js
// Returns the number and pluralized form, like "5 cats" or "1 dog", given
// a noun and count. However, there are a few exceptions. In this exercise,
// add "es" in the following cases:
// 1. the given noun ends with 'o'. For example, '5 potatoes'.
// 2. the noun ends in "f" or "fe" change the "f" to a "v" and add "-es."
// 3. the noun ends in "y", change the "y" to a "i" and add "-es."
// HINT: to replace the last character, you can use `replace()` with Regex.
// For example, if you would like to replace the last 'e' with 'o' in a string `str`,
// you can use `str.replace(/e$/, 'o')`.

const noun = prompt("Enter a noun");
const count = prompt("Enter a number");

console.log(noun);
console.log(count);

if ((count > 1) || (count < 0) || (count == 0) && noun.slice(-1) == /o$/) {
  result = count + " " + noun + "es";
} else if ((count > 1) || (count < 0) || (count == 0) && noun.slice(-1) == /f$/) {
  result = count + " " + noun.replace(/f$/, "v") + "es";
} else if ((count > 1) || (count < 0) || (count == 0) && noun.slice(-1) == /y$/) {
  result = count + " " + noun.replace(/y$/, "i") + "es";
} else(result = count + " " + noun)
// DO NOT CHANGE THIS.
console.log(result);
```

```
0 degrees
Failed

 
0 thieves
Failed

 
1 thief
Passed

 1 family
Passed

 
2 families
Passed


1 party
Passed


1 apple
Passed

2 apples
Failed


10 balloons
Failed


1 balloon
Passed

3 knife
Failed


2 potatoes
Passed

10 tomatoes
Passed


2 parties
Passed


-40 degrees
Failed
```

Comment: This may be more difficult than you think in English. For example, to make "ballon" plural you just need to add an "s", but to make "knife" plural ("knives") you need to change more just the last letter.

Comment: @MichaelM. It's just an exercise, they only have to implement the 3 cases in the instructions.

Comment: `slice(-1) == o$` is not even valid syntax. How did you get this code to run?

Comment: Each word should only be updated once, depending on which case it matches. Use `else if` for mutually exclusive conditions, rather than sequential `if` conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what the problem is, so this code does what you asked for.

```js
const noun = prompt("Enter a noun");
let count = prompt("Enter a number");
if (count > 1 || count <= 0){

if (noun.endsWith("o")) {
    console.log(`${count} ${noun}es`);
} else if (noun.endsWith("f")) {
    console.log(`${count} ${noun.replace(/f$/, "ves")}`);
} else if (noun.endsWith("fe")) {
    console.log(`${count} ${noun.replace(/fe$/, "ves")}`);
} else if (noun.endsWith("y")) {
    console.log(`${count} ${noun.replace(/y$/, "ies")}`);
} else {
    console.log(`${count} ${noun}s`);
}

}else{
console.log(`${count} ${noun}`);

}
```